# Hard light is greyed out, how can i access this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, illustrator-effects, lighting-effects, color-grading

In adobe illustrator im trying to add hard light in gradient options but its greyed out and i cannot for the life of me find out why, could someone help?

[image: hard light]

Comment: the gradient has opacity 0%... so blending mode doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

You have selected only **one colour stop** (The bottom right end of your gradient, which is set to the colour pink and the opacity 0%) of the gradient.

Blending Modes can only be applied to the gradient as a whole. By selecting the object to you have applied the gradient, you can choose different blending modes.